# How to open SWT Browser in Internet Explorer tab?

Tags: java, browser, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an search application that opens a separate search window which is a SWT browser. Instead of separate search window I want that SWT browser to be opened in existing or new IE tab. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no support for this in SWT.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, I have no code to post right now, but I am sure you can extract it form [here](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-base/blob/master/foundation/plugins/org.jboss.tools.foundation.ui/src/org/jboss/tools/foundation/ui/util/BrowserUtility.java#L100).

Please be aware that it opens external browser configured in eclipse preferences, it should be configured to IE on windows by default.

Comment: Thank you for answering query. But the below code you have mentioned needs a URL.
public void openExtenalBrowser(String URL) {
 checkedCreateExternalBrowser(URL,FoundationUIPlugin.PLUGIN_ID,FoundationUIPlugin.getDefault().getLog());
}

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn't get your question right, I thought you need to open external browser.